# Replace data in an array with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am using a digital elevation model as an array, and I want to create a new array with only the pixels below a certain value. I tried using a for loop.

Here is the operation with simpler data :

```
import numpy as np

array1 = array2 = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
array2 = array2.astype("float") #np.nan doesn't work with integers

for row in array2: 
    for item in row:
        if item > 3.0:
            item=np.nan

print(np.array_equal(array1,array2))
```

The arrays remain equal after the loop is over. Do you know why the values won't be replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only change `item` you need insert `item` in `array2`, you can use `np.where` like below:

```
>>> array1 = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> array2 = np.where(array1 > 3, np.nan, array1)
>>> array2
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3., nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan]])

>>> np.array_equal(array1, array2)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Values are not replaced because `item` is a copy of each array item.

Beside this, using a pure-Python loop is not efficient. Consider vectorizing the code with `array2[array2 > 3.0] = np.nan`.